# Linking an object to a jquery function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to link together an object in JS to a function of a button in Jquery. I've linked Jquery to my HTML so it is technically working, however, it's a specific project that is requiring the buttons to display the info. in the object. I've tried editing it on my own and I keep getting stuck and I'm not sure how to link the two. The instructions are included as well.

```
 // create a JavaScript object here with the following fields: firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice
    function About(firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice, tellMeMore) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.homeOffice = homeOffice;
        this.tellMeMore = tellMeMore;
    };
    var about01 = new About("Megan", "Adams", "Customer Serice Rep", "Penn Field", "I have been working at in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art.");

    // using jQuery and the object above, display the information as the appropriate button is clicked


    var button = document.querySelectorAll ('button');

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {
            $(".name").fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });

     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button1").click(function() {
            $(".job").fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button2").click(function() {
            $(".office").fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button3").click(function() {
            $(".more").fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title role="title">CEP Engineering Application</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <article>
            <header role=banner>
         <h1>About Me</h1>
      </header>
                <img src="img/IMG_1989.jpg" alt="Megan Adams Picture" style="width:250px;height:460px; "class="img">
        <section>
         <button type="button" class="button">Name</button>
           <p class="name">Megan Adams</p>
        </section>
        <section>
           <button type="button" class="button1">Job Title</button>
           <p class="job">Customer Service Reo</p>
     </section>
     <section>
          <button type="button" class="button2">Home Office</button>
          <p class="office">Penn Field</p>
     </section>
     <section>
          <button type="button" class="button3">Tell Me More</button>
          <p class="more">I have been working at in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art. </p>
      </section>
      <script src="init.js"></script>
          </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When and where should the values of the object be displayed? Note, multiple `.ready()` calls are not necessary.

Comment: Do you want it to `console.log` the info, or change the button html?

Comment: And your html code would help as well

Comment: the values of the object need to be displayed in the button and need to show when you click on the button. I will add the HTML

Comment: What should occur for the `".name"` `class`, where both `"firstName"` and `"lastName"` properties exist at the object?

Comment: the instructions are :      -Create a JavaScript object in the init.js file with the following fields: firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice, tellMeMore
-Using jQuery, as the user clicks on the button, reveal the appropriate information using the values from the JS object

Comment: @guest271314 it should be my info- i could have created the object incorrectly as well.. I'm very new to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited both the code and html and made them much smaller.

now have a look at attribute `data` and read the comment to understand, how this work.

```js
 // create a JavaScript object here with the following fields: firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice
    function About(firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice, tellMeMore) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
        this.homeOffice = homeOffice;
        this.tellMeMore = tellMeMore;
    };
    var about01 = new About("Megan", "Adams", "Customer Serice Rep", "Penn Field", "I have been working at in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art.");

    // using jQuery and the object above, display the information as the appropriate button is clicked
    

    var button = document.querySelectorAll ('button');

    $(document).ready(function() {
    // present the values, 
    $("section > p").each(function(){
    // more dynamic approch
     var field = $(this).attr("data");
     var value ="";
     if (field){
     field.split(" ").forEach((x)=> {
       if (value== "")
         value = about01[x];
         else value += " " + about01[x] // firstName and lastName
     });
      $(this).html(value)
    }
  });
    
     // now you only need one method click to display toggle p 
        $(".button").click(function() {
           // you know that p exist under button
           // so go back to parent of the current object and then find the p and toggle it.
            $(this).parent().find("p").fadeToggle(1000);
        });
    });
```

```html
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<article>
            <header role=banner>
         <h1>About Me</h1>
      </header>
     <img src="img/IMG_1989.jpg" alt="Megan Adams Picture" style="width:250px;height:460px; "class="img">
        <section>
         <button type="button" class="button">Name</button>
           <p data="firstName lastName" ></p>
        </section>
        <section>
           <button type="button" class="button">jobTitle</button>
           <p data="jobTitle"></p>
     </section>
     <section>
          <button type="button" class="button">homeOffice</button>
          <p data="homeOffice"></p>
     </section>
     <section>
          <button type="button" class="button">Tell Me More</button>
          <p data="tellMeMore"> </p>
      </section>
      <script src="init.js"></script>
          </article>
```

Comment: thanks! this was what i was looking for. I will try this.

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like below using jQuery `$(selector).html(value);`

```js
// create a JavaScript object here with the following fields: firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice
function About(firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice, tellMeMore) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
  this.homeOffice = homeOffice;
  this.tellMeMore = tellMeMore;
};
var about01 = new About("Megan", "Adams", "Resolutions Specialist", "Penn Field", "I have been working at HomeAway in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art.");
$(".name").html(`${about01.firstName} ${about01.lastName}`);
$(".job").html(about01.jobTitle);
$(".office").html(about01.homeOffice);
$(".more").html(about01.tellMeMore);

// using jQuery and the object above, display the information as the appropriate button is clicked


var button = document.querySelectorAll('button');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".name").fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button1").click(function() {
    $(".job").fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button2").click(function() {
    $(".office").fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button3").click(function() {
    $(".more").fadeToggle(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title role="title">CEP Engineering Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <header role=banner>
      <h1>About Me</h1>
    </header>
    <img src="img/IMG_1989.jpg" alt="Megan Adams Picture" style="width:250px;height:460px; " class="img">
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button">Name</button>
      <p class="name">Megan Adams</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button1">Job Title</button>
      <p class="job">Customer Service Reo</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button2">Home Office</button>
      <p class="office">Penn Field</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button3">Tell Me More</button>
      <p class="more">I have been working at in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art. </p>
    </section>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I will try that! Thank you! I added in the HTML.

Comment: Does my code work for you? If not, what should I change

Comment: So, I need each button to say "name" and then clicked it'll show my name, etc. I've got it linked to my HTML ,so, it's technically working, but, we're supposed to be connecting it to the object. Here's a screencast video of what it should look like https://www.screencast.com/t/r40LLR0NY3

Answer (score 0):

Only a single `jQuery()` is necessary. You can use get the property names of the object using `Array.prototype.keys()` convert the `className` of current element `.toLowerCase()` within `.html()`, `.filter()` the property names where `.indexOf()` `className` of the current element is greater than `-1`, `.map()` and `.join()` the result

```js
$(function() {
  function About(firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice, tellMeMore) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    this.homeOffice = homeOffice;
    this.tellMeMore = tellMeMore;
  };

  const about01 = new About("Megan", "Adams", "Customer Serice Rep", "Penn Field", "I have been working at in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art.");
  
  const keys = Object.keys(about01);
  
  $(".name, .job, .office, .more").html(function() {
      const el = this;
      return keys.filter(function(value) { 
                 return value.toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf(el.className) > -1
               })
               .map(function(value) {
                 return about01[value]
               }).join(" ")
             
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div class="name"></div>
<div class="job"></div>
<div class="office"></div>
<div class="more"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use one `document.ready` method in your JS.

What you can do to achieve this is add a click event listener to all your buttons. Then when a button is clicked you can refer to the button clicked using `$(this)`. The element which you want to append text to is the paragraph next to the button clicked. You can get the paragraph element by using `$(this).next('p')`. Using the class name of the paragraph you can then work out which object property to display.

Below, I have used an object called `classToProp` which maps your class names to strings retrieved from your `About` object. Using this you can display the specific information you want to the adjoining `p` tag.

See working example below:

```js
function About(firstName, lastName, jobTitle, homeOffice, tellMeMore) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
  this.homeOffice = homeOffice;
  this.tellMeMore = tellMeMore;
};

var about01 = new About("Megan", "Adams", "Customer Serice Rep", "Penn Field", "I have been working at in customer service since December 2018 and transferred over to the Resolutions Department in fall of 2018. In my spare time I love watching scary movies, listening to true crime podcasts and music, and making art.");

var classToProp = {
  name: about01.firstName + " " + about01.lastName,
  job: about01.jobTitle,
  office: about01.homeOffice,
  more: about01.tellMeMore
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var nextP = $(this).next('p');
    var className = nextP.attr("class");
    var txt = nextP.text(); // get the text from the paragraph
    nextP.text(txt ? "" : classToProp[className]); // if the text is empty, display the associated property from your object, otherwise, if it already has text make it empty - this allows for a toggle effect
  });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title role="title">CEP Engineering Application</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <header role=banner>
      <h1>About Me</h1>
    </header>
    <img src="img/IMG_1989.jpg" alt="" style="width:250px;height:460px; " class="img">
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button">Name</button>
      <p class="name"></p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button1">Job Title</button>
      <p class="job"></p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button2">Home Office</button>
      <p class="office"></p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <button type="button" class="button3">Tell Me More</button>
      <p class="more"></p>
    </section>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```